# Problem with opening pdf file in site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pdf

I have pdf file in serwer and link to it. In local host when i click on link pdf file display in site. On server I've got popup with asking to download file. How to change type from application/octet-stream to application/pdf to display pdf normal on site?
Here is screen after clicking on link:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with using solution from this site:
http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/06-08-2007/force-a-pdf-to-download

Thanks **Joost Evertse**

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the listed solutions are reported not to work half the time, is because using the default MIME association or setting the Content-Type header in `<Files>` or `<FilesMatch>` (for the PDF file extension) **will have no effect on PDF files that are dynamically transferred via PHP code** (i.e., `readfile()`)...

[To force a PDF to open in the browser rather than downloading](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/forcing-a-pdf-or-doc-to-open-in-browser-rather-than-downloading), you should use `LocationMatch` instead:

```
<LocationMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
    ForceType application/pdf
    Header set Content-Disposition inline
</LocationMatch>
```

This way it picks up on transfers that are not direct from the file-system.

Answer (score 1):

If it a unix server add an entry for pdfs in  /etc/mime.types, if it's a Windows server, add a mime type in IIS.

Comment: I've got "16_pzt-pdf.pdf: application/pdf"

Comment: Are the files in /usr/share/mime world readable? If not do a chmod a+r /usr/share/mime/* and try to download the file again.

Comment: Folder mime not exist. I only see mimelink where is another folder "image"

Comment: Let's find out how your webserver is configured. Where does the directive TypesConfig in httpd.conf point at? /etc/mime.types?

Comment: Another thing to look at:Are there already handlers defined for pdfs in ht httpd.conf? Look for AddType directives for pdfs.

Comment: answer for 1st question: yes point at /etc/mime.types,
2nd: there is no defined pdf in httpd.conf

Comment: @JoostEvertse let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1354/discussion-between-woocash-and-joost-evertse)